# Saving Text Files - Scoped Storage Android 11

Tags: java, android, libgdx, storage, scoped-storage

Is there a way to create and save text files outside of the Android/data folder in external storage? I am creating a music app and I added a preset manager so users can save, load, and edit preset files (which worked great before Android 11), I don’t want these files to be automatically removed if the app is uninstalled. That would be like if Photoshop deleted all of your Photoshop documents when Photoshop is uninstalled, that’s terrible! These are files that the user saves and they can be deleted separately if the user wants to.

There has to be a way around this but I haven’t been able to find anything that works. `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` looked very promising, until I saw that Android has removed this option too.

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

> You can no longer use the ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE intent action to
> request access to the following directories:
>
> - The root directory of the internal storage volume.
> - The root directory of each SD card volume that the device manufacturer considers to be reliable, regardless of whether the card
>   is emulated or removable. A reliable volume is one that an app can
>   successfully access most of the time.
> - The Download directory.

I’ve read Google Play only allows `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in apps that need it (like file browsers, or anti-virus, etc) which likely will not work in my case. I don’t want to rely on only targeting older API’s so `requestLegacyExternalStorage` won’t work either.

Everything I’ve looked into appears to be a dead end. Is there anything else I can do?

Here is a short test program (I’m using LibGDX), which at the moment can only save to the root location:

```
Android/data/com.mygdx.filetest/files/
```

**[core] FileTest.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Files;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;

public class FileTest implements ApplicationListener {
    private NativePermissions permissions;
    private Files.FileType fileType;
    private String directory = "TestDir/";
    private String name = "text.txt";
       
    public FileTest(final NativePermissions permissions){     
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void create(){
        fileType = getFileType();
        if (permissions != null){
            permissions.checkExternalStoragePermission();
        } else {
            permissionGranted();
        }
    }
    private Files.FileType getFileType(){
        switch(Gdx.app.getType()) {
            case Android:
                return Files.FileType.External;
            default:
                return Files.FileType.Local;
        }
    }
    
    @Override public void render(){ ScreenUtils.clear(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1); }
    @Override public void resize(int width, int height) {}
    @Override public void pause(){}
    @Override public void resume(){}
    @Override public void dispose (){}
    
    public void permissionGranted() {
        FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.getFileHandle(directory+name, fileType); 
        if (fileHandle!=null) fileHandle.writeString("test", false);
    }
}
```

**[android] AndroidLauncher.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    private final FileTest application;
    private final int STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE = 1;
    private boolean dialogBoxShowing = false;
    
    public AndroidLauncher(){
        final AndroidPermissions permissions = new AndroidPermissions(this);
        application = new FileTest(permissions);
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(application, config);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(final int requestCode, final String permissions[], final int[] grantResults) {
        dialogBoxShowing = false;
        if (requestCode == STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                permissionGranted();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission DENIED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    public void promptExternalStoragePermission() {
        if (dialogBoxShowing) return;
        dialogBoxShowing = true;
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(AndroidLauncher.this);
                builder.setMessage("To save user presets and custom settings, allow access to your phone’s storage.");
                builder.setCancelable(false);
                // reverse these buttons to put "NO" on left and "YES" on right
                builder.setPositiveButton("NOT NOW", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialogBoxShowing = false;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                builder.setNegativeButton("CONTINUE", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AndroidLauncher.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);
                    }
                });
                builder.create().show();
            }
        });
    }
    public void permissionGranted(){ application.permissionGranted(); }
}
```

**[core] NativePermissions.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

public interface NativePermissions {
    public void checkExternalStoragePermission();
}
```

**[android] AndroidPermissions.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;

public class AndroidPermissions implements NativePermissions {
    private final AndroidLauncher context;
    
    public AndroidPermissions(final AndroidLauncher context){
        this.context = context;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void checkExternalStoragePermission() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            context.permissionGranted();
        } else {
            context.promptExternalStoragePermission();
        }
    }
}
```

**[android] AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mygdx.filetest">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:isGame="true"
        android:appCategory="game"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mygdx.filetest.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="fullUser"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lott of fuss.

You can in the classic way save your files to the public Documents directory.

Or use SAF with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE for that directory.

Both dont need 'all files access'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the "classic way". I've been using LibGDX, so I'm not very familiar with native Android and this is one of the rare times I've needed to work with it. Does SAF work on the Documents director because it can access directories that already exist on Android? However, I can't use SAF to create a directory for my app on the device root of the device, is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: The classic way is as you did it before SAF. As always. And your last theorem is not ok.

Comment: It appears this is a lot more complicated. I originally thought this was an Android permissions issue and once that was sorted out then I could use the LibGDX External FileHandle as usual, but according to the LibGDX documentation the External FileHandle paths are now relative to the app-specific external storage directory (Android/data/...). https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling If I can get the External FileHandle to access the Documents folder, then that will be great. However, I'm not sure if I can do that now.

Comment: `the External FileHandle paths are now relative to the app-specific external storage directory` Well then you should consult those developers..

Comment: I'm working on a question for the LibGDX discord now that I found that. Hopefully someone has a work around for this. Thank you for your responses. :)

Comment: I am accepting your answer, I got it working by obtaining the absolute path to the Documents folder using: 
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath();

Then using the Absolute LibGDX FileHandle instead of External. 

However, I am having a separate problem now. If I uninstall and reinstalled the app, I cannot access the file anymore because Android thinks it is a new application and denies access. My new problem is very different from this one, so I’m accepting your answer and creating new question. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes this is normal behaviour. So after reinstall use SAF ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user select the Documents folder or ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT to let the user select a file in Documents folder. But.. if you need a handle from LibGDX...

Comment: Anyhow your app should sowieso give the user the ability to select a file with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT. You get a nice uri for the file then. If LibGDX cannot handle an uri then contact the developers. You can yourself open an InputStream or parcelFileDescriptor for the uri. LibGDX should be able to use them too. If not contact the developers. Its.. such  little work to add all those possibilities...

Comment: Yes, I need a way to create LibGDX FileHandle, which can be created with a path (String) or java.io.File. If I can obtain either of these things on the Android side, then I can pass it to the LibGDX FileHandle no problem. It's the Android side that I'm not familiar with. If you would like to take a look at my new question, it is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70565499/accessing-files-created-by-previous-installation-on-android-scoped-storage-and

Comment: As a side note, I was able to remove all of that code to perform the permission request by using the public Documents folder, so thank you for that suggestion too. It is very nice to remove all of that. :)

Comment: I forgot to mention that LibGDX is open source. Unfortunately, I do not understand how much of their stuff works as they are beyond my skill level, especially on the Android side. Here is the source code for FileHandle core: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.java and the Android backend: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidFileHandle.java That's mostly Greek to me, but maybe that will help provide a way to get it to work with Android's file access.