# Accessing Files Created by Previous Installation on Android - Scoped Storage Android 11

Tags: java, android, libgdx, storage, scoped-storage

I am using LibGDX to develop a music app with a preset manager that uses LibGDX’s FileHandle to manage the files and directories. This has been working great until I updated to Android 11 (API 30), now I’m running into problems accessing files due to the limitations from Android’s new scoped storage.

I am trying to use Android’s public Documents directory to store and manage my preset files. I access the Documents directory by getting its absolute path with:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath()
```

And then I use that path to instantiate LibGDX’s Absolute FileHandle to manage my directories and files.

My problem is that if I uninstall the app and reinstall it, I no longer have access to the old files since Android treats the new installation like a completely separate app. This is explained here:
https://commonsware.com/blog/2021/11/06/about-environment-undeprecations.html

In the sample code below, I create the following directory:

```
Documents/TestDir/
```

Is there a way I can get permission from the user to modify files in that specific directory (even after the app is reinstalled) and then use its absolute path to manage it via LibGDX’s FileHandle? Can I prompt the user myself or use one of the existing Android storage access systems (like Storage Access Framework) to accomplish this?

**Additional Points:** I want to avoid using the `Android/data` folder to store the preset files because I don’t want the files to be deleted automatically if the app is uninstalled (these are user created files so they can be deleted separately if the user wants to). I do want to continue using LibGDX’s FileHandle because it provides a lot of methods that I depend on for my preset manager. I also plan on creating an iOS version in the future and LibGDX is cross-platform.

Here is the API for LibGDX’s FileHandle (in case this might be useful):
https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/files/FileHandle.html

Here is the code for my short test program. Thank you!

**[core] FileTest.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Files;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle;
import com.badlogic.gdx.utils.ScreenUtils;

public class FileTest implements ApplicationListener {
    private FileAccess fileAccess;
    private String directoryName = "TestDir/";
    private String fileName = "text.txt";
    
    public FileTest(final FileAccess fileAccess){       
        this.fileAccess = fileAccess;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void create(){
        // get absolute path to Android Documents directory
        String documentsPath = fileAccess.getDocumentsAbsolutePath() + "/";
        
        // FILE HANDLING: with LibGDX FileHandle
        FileHandle file = Gdx.files.getFileHandle(documentsPath+directoryName+fileName, Files.FileType.Absolute);
        file.writeString("test", false);
    }
    
    @Override public void render(){ ScreenUtils.clear(0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1); }
    @Override public void resize(int width, int height) {}
    @Override public void pause(){}
    @Override public void resume(){}
    @Override public void dispose (){}
}
```

**[android] AndroidLauncher.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;

public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication {
    private final FileTest application;
    
    public AndroidLauncher(){
        application = new FileTest(new AndroidFileAccess());
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
        initialize(application, config);
    }
}
```

**[core] FileAccess.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

public interface FileAccess {
    String getDocumentsAbsolutePath();
}
```

**[android] AndroidFileAccess.java**

```
package com.mygdx.filetest;

import android.os.Environment;

public class AndroidFileAccess implements FileAccess {
    @Override
    public String getDocumentsAbsolutePath() {
        // get absolute path to Android's public Documents directory
        return Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS).getAbsolutePath();
    }
}
```

**[android] AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mygdx.filetest">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:isGame="true"
        android:appCategory="game"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/GdxTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mygdx.filetest.AndroidLauncher"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:screenOrientation="fullUser"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenSize|screenLayout">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: You can solve your problem with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. But probably you do not want that.

Comment: `don’t want the files to be deleted automatically if the app is uninstalled` Did you try `android:hasFragileUserData="true"` in application tag of manifest?

Comment: I've read that Google Play is strict with MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and will reject apps they don't think need it. I'm not sure if my app would qualify for this. I've also posted on the LibGDX discord and the hasFragileUserData was mentioned but was told that it doesn't work well at the time being. Plus, the Documents folder is much more convenient to access than the Android/data (I don't use my phone for that much, but I have over 180 other folders there). This is not really relevant for this particular task (managing presets), but it will be in the future with other features I plan on adding.

Comment: It seems like it would be simple enough to merely ask the user for permission to access a specific directory (which I could prompt for when launching the app), then once they give permission I can get the file path (absolute file path in this case) to use with the LibGDX FileHandle to access anything inside that directory. Before accessing a file Android could simply check to make sure permission was given for that directory (or even a specific file) and then allow access or deny it. I don't understand why Android had to make this so difficult, but it is very frustrating!

Comment: You cannot ask for permission. You can only ask the user if he will select a specific directory using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. But after that you will only have uries for the files. And even if you manage to decode a file path from those uries you cannot use those paths as you have no access rights then.

Comment: So there is no possible way to make it work with LibGDX FileHandle then? This is frustrating as I put a lot of work into the preset manager and it has been working perfectly. What are my options to be able to use the Documents folder? Seems like I'd have to scrap LibGDX FileHandle entirely, create a new interface for accessing files to call from the LibGDX core and write the entire Android backend using the SAF. I've done very little native Android programming, I'm not sure I can do that. I was hoping to release before the end of the year (that didn't happen) and now this is a major setback.

Comment: You can always make a copy of a file if you have an uri for it. Copy to file system then use the path of the copy.

Comment: Making copies was mentioned in the LibGDX discord too. In the future I am planning on adding functionality to work with audio files and I had hoped there was a better way, I'd like to avoid making copies of potentially large audio files on mobile devices with limited storage. But for the moment with small text files, this is much simpler than re-writing LibGDX's FileHandle. Maybe by the time I get to implementing audio files Android will change everything again. (probably for the worse given how things are going *sigh*) I did find one more thing while watching a video on scoped storage...

Comment: Are you familiar with Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)? According to this video FUSE was implemented to allow API's that use file paths instead of URI's (like LibGDX FileHandle?), but not a lot of specifics was provided: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjyYCUW-9tY&t=256s Googling this did not turn up much info, I can't find a tutorials or even an API for how to actually implement it. The section called "Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE)" mentions it, but not a lot of details: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/scoped This sounds promising, but I'm still not sure if it is a viable option.

Comment: Sorry, i will not follow your links. You stand alone..;-)

Comment: If you are worried that I'm providing questionable links, you don't have to click them if you are concerned. The first one is a YouTube video called "Storage access with Android 11" uploaded by Android Developers (an official Android developers channel), the part about FUSE starts at 4:16. The second one is on Source.Android.com and the article is titled "Scoped Storage", see the section called "Using scoped storage with FUSE". That should be enough info to find these if you don't want to click the links. I'm just trying to understand it and see if it will work for what I need. That is all. :)

Comment: Those are the best sources I've found on Filesystem in Userspace (FUSE) so far, but they didn't provide much info on it. It sounds promising, but I'm still not sure if it will actually work with LibGDX or not. I can't find any specific API that I can look at to figure out what it does. The sources I found gave fairly vague descriptions, but did not mention where to go to find out more info or tutorials on how to use it. I'm usually pretty good at researching information, but there doesn't seem to be a lot of info on this. Where can I go to find out more about it?

Comment: Ok, I wasn't sure what you meant by your comment, but thank you for the help you've provided thus far. I might remove this question and ask a new one about FUSE instead. I don't want to spam Stack Overflow with multiple questions on this same problem. Thanks again.

Comment: Yea, google messed up and im sure pissed off a lot of developers. You can however use manage external storage on amazon. They should let the user decide if we can use it, it shouldnt be a rejectable permission.

Comment: I'm planning on releasing on Google Play because that's the default app store, which rules out manage external storage unfortunately. I've created a feature request to use the new Android file system on the LibGDX Github, but no response from the devs. I've asked on the LibGDX Discord, but no solution to this yet. At this point, it appears I'm going to have to learn Storage Access Framework (I think this is best for my needs) and code the backend myself. I'm not an Android programmer so it'll be time consuming to get up to speed and fix something I've had working. It is extremely frustrating!